# How to use double as the default type for floating numbers in PyTorch

Tags: python, image-processing, machine-learning, computer-vision, pytorch

I want all the floating numbers in my PyTorch code double type by default, how can I do that?

Answer (score 9):

You are looking for [`torch.set_default_tensor_type`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.set_default_tensor_type):

```
torch.set_default_tensor_type(torch.DoubleTensor)
```

Aletrnatively, you can use [`torch.set_default_dtype`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.set_default_dtype):

```
torch.set_default_dtype(torch.float64)
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use for that `torch.set_default_dtype`.

It is true that using `torch.set_default_tensor_type` will also have a similar effect, but `torch.set_default_tensor_type` not only sets the default data type, but also sets the default values for the **device** where the tensor is allocated, and the **layout** of the tensor.